# What's the difference in F# between a private member and a let val?

Tags: f#

Question in the title. Suppose I have:

```
namespace Namespace
module Module =
  type public Type() =
    let Z y = 2 * y
    member private this.z y = 2 * y
```

What is the difference between Z and z?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing to consider is that with reflection, the private member becomes accessible.

Also, you can't call the code in `z` until after the constructor has completed

Comment: Oh, so the let's are declared during construction. Thanks!